# Linq Query - Using select, group by, joins, functions, and order by at once?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a fairly complex query that I'm trying to implement via Linq. I'm struggling to find a way to:

- Order by a select return (the IFNULL result that's selected is used in the group by)
- Get all the distinct results a group by in sql would

How can I reproduce this query via Linq?

```
select
company.id
IFNULL(employee.team_name, employee.name) AS team_name
FROM company 
INNER JOIN branch on branch.parent_company_id = company.uuid
INNER JOIN map_employee_to_branch on map_employee_to_branch.machine_uuid = branch.uuid
INNER JOIN employee on employee.id = map_employee_to_branch.employee_id
where company.name = "Whatever" AND map_employee_to_branch.isActive = true
GROUP BY map_employee_to_branch.employee_id, company.id
ORDER BY company.id, employee.title, team_name, employee.name
```

Comment: Can you provide the LINQ code that you *have* come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your inner joins are handled by your navigation property mappings, and I'm making some assumptions about your entity property names.

```
(from company in context.Companies
where company.name = "Whatever"
from branch in company.Branches
from m in branch.MapEmployeeToBranches
where m.IsActive
let employee = m.Employee
select new { 
    companyId = company.id, 
    employeeId = employee.id
    employee.title,
    teamName = employee.team_name ?? employee.name,
    employee.name
} into projection
orderby projection.id, projection.title, projection.teamName, projection.name
group new { projection.companyId, projection.teamName }
    by new { projection.employeeId, projection.companyId }
```

Comment: Is there a way to group by two columns but return all columns - similar to the SQL use of group by?

I suppose I could get all the row ids for each grouped table then query them again, join all their columns, then convert it to a custom object.

This seems incredibly verbose and less performant that just running a regular query.

Comment: @EndOfAll: Sure. Your original SQL was only returning two columns, so I only included those two columns. Replace `group new {...} by ...` with `group projection by ...`.

Comment: Regarding verbosity, this is only a few more words than your SQL, and it could be a lot more concise if you were willing to repeat `employee.team_name ?? employee.name`, but you specifically asked about reusing the value from the SELECT in the GROUP By, so I wanted to show how that could be done. Regarding performance, I'd be curious to see metrics. It probably performs roughly the same as your SQL query.